# IOS Realm Swift Other Realm Accessed from incorrect thread

Tags: swift, ios8, realm

I get this error msg `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread'` when i switch to `Other Realm`. Everything is working fine when i use `default Realm`.

Couldn't figure out which part cause the error.

```
let realm:Realm!
var queue = dispatch_queue_create("realmQueue", nil)

func init(){
   var realmName = "test.realm"
   let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
   let path = documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent(realmName)

   realm = Realm(path: path)
}

func loadCustomer(){

    dispatch_async(queue){
        //let realm = Realm()
        var results = self.realm.objects()

        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

my bad.

```
dispatch_async(queue){
   realm = Realm(path:path)
}
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! As a rule of thumb, you don't normally need to save references to Realm objects as static variables or properties. Realm automatically caches Realm object references internally, so if you simply call Realm(path:) again, it'll re-use the previous reference, even on separate threads. Good luck!